# How to debug the supabase_flutter repository and other melos based monorepos locally?

Tags: flutter, supabase, dart-pub, supabase-flutter, melos

I'm trying to debug the [supabase_flutter](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-flutter) repository locally. Their is some functionality within the packages, that I can test best within an app I'm working on. Therefore I'm trying to use the local repo as a dependency within the pubspec.yaml of my app.

I already forked and cloned the repo to my local machine, initialized everything with melos and added the local package as an dependency according to the [README](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-flutter).

When I'm trying to inspect an imported function in my app from the package 'supabase_flutter', the related local file of the repo opens as expected. But when I'm trying to inspect a function from the 'postgrest' package, I only get send to a copy of the file in the .pub-cache directory.

This means, that I am unable to test any changes I make to files of the 'postgrest' package in my app, because the copied file in the .pub-cache directory doesn't get updated. I can only debug changes that I make to the 'supabase_flutter' package, like adding a `print` statement to the `Supabase.initialize` function. My initial goal was to debug the `PostgrestTransformBuilder<T> range(int from, int to, {String? referencedTable})` function at `packages/postgrest/lib/src/postgrest_transform_builder.dart` and add a `print` statement there.

I already tried different combinations of `pub get`, `pub upgrade` and `melos bootstrap` together with deleting the .pub-cache directory multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Supabase-specific question, but rather a question of how the Dart packaging system works.

Add the following in your pubspec.yaml file

```yaml
melos_managed_dependency_overrides: functions_client,gotrue,postgrest,realtime_client,storage_client,yet_another_json_isolate
dependency_overrides:
  functions_client:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/functions_client
  gotrue:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/gotrue
  postgrest:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/postgrest
  realtime_client:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/realtime_client
  storage_client:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/storage_client
  supabase:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/supabase
  yet_another_json_isolate:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/yet_another_json_isolate
  supabase_flutter:
    path: ../supabase-flutter/packages/supabase_flutter
```

Then I would try the following:

- Delete the `pubspec.lock` file in your Flutter app
- Run `melos bs` in the supabase_flutter package
- Run `pub get` in your Flutter app
- Verify in your `pubspec.lock` file in your Flutter app that it is using the local version of the dependencies.

Comment: Thank you for the ideas. I performed the steps you mentioned, but the problem still remains even after deleting the `pubspec.lock` file and regenerating it after `melos bs`. I looked through the `pubspec.lock` and all transitive dependencies from the `supabase_flutter` repo have still `hosted` as source instead `path`.

Comment: @Michel I have edited my answer. Hopefully this would do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution / a workaround for my needs. According to the `README` of the [supabase_flutter](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-flutter/tree/main) repo, it is sufficient to add the local path of the `supabase_flutter` package to the project you want to import it, like:

```yaml
  supabase_flutter:
    path: <your-path-to-the-local-supabase-flutter-repo>/packages/supabase_flutter
```

But the other packages in the monorepo still get imported from pub.dev instead of their local versions. The solution for me was to change all the dependencies to other packages from the monorepo in all `pubspec.yaml` of the packages. For example, in the `pubspec.yaml` of the local `supabase_flutter` package:

```yaml
  supabase:
    path: <your-path-to-the-local-supabase-flutter-repo>/packages/supabase
```

Only then and after running `melos bs` in the repo again, the correct local versions of all packages are imported correctly, which then allows for debugging of their functions.

I'm not sure if I misunderstood the functionalities of melos or rather the dart packaging system itself, and maybe this is intended behavior. Unfortunately, I didn't find any clue for this procedure in the `README` of the [supabase_flutter](https://github.com/supabase/supabase-flutter/tree/main) repo.